# How do I install Ubuntu for phone on Samsung Galaxy Mini?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, samsung

Any completed procedure to install Ubuntu on Samsung Galaxy Mini.

Answer (score -1):

Browse these pages for help:

http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone

http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android